# The line $x-1=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z-2}{3}$ turns into a plane after simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given this "line" in 3D: $x-1=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z-2}{3}$.

However, once I simplify it, I get a plane: 
$$x-1=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z-2}{3}$$
$$6x-6=3y-3=2z-4$$
$$6x-6-3y+3-2z+4=0$$
$$6x-3y-2z-2=0$$

Why does this happen? How can a equation that is supposedly a line according to my textbook turn into a plane by simplification? The steps are as far as I know valid.

Comment: How do you step from `a=b=c` to `a-b-c=0` on the last but one line?

Comment: you have two equalities which will give two planes equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation
$$
x-1=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z-2}{3}
$$
means
\begin{cases}
x-1=\dfrac{y-1}{2} \\[6px]
\dfrac{y-1}{2}=\dfrac{z-2}{3}
\end{cases}
or, equivalently,
\begin{cases}
x-1=\dfrac{y-1}{2} \\[6px]
x-1=\dfrac{z-2}{3}
\end{cases}

These represent the intersection of two planes which is generally not a plane.

---

The points on the line can also be described by
\begin{cases}
x-1=t \\[6px]
\dfrac{y-1}{2}=t \\[6px]
\dfrac{z-2}{3}=t
\end{cases}
that can be rewritten
\begin{cases}
x=t+1 \\[4px]
y=2t+1 \\[4px]
z=3t+2
\end{cases}
If you arbitrarily assign a value to $t$ you get a point on the line and, conversely, to any point of the line there corresponds a unique value for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the simplification incorrectly. The problem lies in the step between:

$$6x−6=3y−3=2z−4$$
and
$$6x−6−3y+3−2z+4=0$$

For example, $1 = 1 = 1$, but  $1 - 1 - 1 \not = 0$!

It should generally set off a red flag if you start with three equalities and end up with just two. The issue becomes evident when we break down the steps in your simplification:
$$
\begin{align}
6x−6=3y−3=2z−4 \\
6x−6-3y+3=0=2z−4 -3y+3 \\
6x−6-3y+3-2z+4=-2z+4=-3y+3
\end{align}
$$

So, as you can see, the simplification doesn't work.